# No conversion for undefined on selection field - Odoo v9 community

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-9

I have a selection field on a module for Odoov9 Community

But, everytime, I click on it, to select a record it throws me this error:

```
Error: No conversion for undefined

http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:732
Traceback:
wrap@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:732:29
wrapping_list<.__getitem__@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:787:16
py.PY_getItem@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:610:19
py.evaluate@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:1403:24
py.evaluate@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:1404:21
py.evaluate@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:1397:35
py.evaluate@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:1409:34
py.eval@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:1453:16
eval_domains/<@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:862:32
_.forEach@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js:145:9
_.mixin/</_.prototype[name]@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js:1484:29
eval_domains@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:853:5
eval_domains/<@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:867:32
_.forEach@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js:145:9
_.mixin/</_.prototype[name]@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js:1484:29
eval_domains@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:853:5
eval_domains/<@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:867:32
_.forEach@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js:145:9
_.mixin/</_.prototype[name]@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js:1484:29
eval_domains@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:853:5
pyeval@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:946:16
eval_arg@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:957:16
ensure_evaluated@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/pyeval.js:980:21
.call@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/data_model.js:56:9
DataSet<.name_search@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/framework/data.js:537:16
CompletionFieldMixin.get_search_result@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/views/form_common.js:192:33
FieldMany2One<.render_editable/<.source@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/views/form_relational_widgets.js:271:17
._search@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/jquery.ui/jquery-ui.js:7404:3
$.widget/</proxiedPrototype[prop]</<@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/jquery.ui/jquery-ui.js:415:19
.search@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/jquery.ui/jquery-ui.js:7396:10
$.widget/</proxiedPrototype[prop]</<@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/jquery.ui/jquery-ui.js:415:19
$.widget.bridge/$.fn[name]/<@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/jquery.ui/jquery-ui.js:513:19
.each@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:383:49
jQuery.prototype.each@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:136:24
$.widget.bridge/$.fn[name]@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/jquery.ui/jquery-ui.js:499:4
FieldMany2One<.render_editable/<@http://localhost:8070/web/static/src/js/views/form_relational_widgets.js:189:21
jQuery.event.dispatch@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:4640:50
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@http://localhost:8070/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:4309:41
```

I'm not fond on new javascript libraries for Odoo, so, I don't know where to start looking for this, has this happened to anyone before?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is the invoice model code(where I'm calling it from):

```
class account_move_line(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.move.line"

document_class_id = new_fields.Many2one(
    'sii.document_class',
    'Document Type',
    related='move_id.document_class_id',
    store=True,
    readonly=True,
)
document_number = new_fields.Char(
    string='Document Number',
    related='move_id.document_number',
    store=True,
    readonly=True,
    )


class account_journal_sii_document_class(models.Model):
    _name = "account.journal.sii_document_class"
    _description = "Journal SII Documents"

    def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        result = []
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        result.append((record.id, record.sii_document_class_id.name))
    return result

    _order = 'journal_id desc, sequence, id'

    sii_document_class_id = new_fields.Many2one('sii.document_class',
                                            'Document Type', required=True)
    sequence_id = new_fields.Many2one(
        'ir.sequence', 'Entry Sequence', required=False,
        help="""This field contains the information related to the numbering \
    of the documents entries of this document type.""")
     journal_id = new_fields.Many2one(
        'account.journal', 'Journal', required=True)
    sequence = new_fields.Integer('Sequence',)
```

The invoice view definitions:

```
<xpath expr="//group[last()]" position="inside">
<filter string="Document Type" icon="terp-folder-orange" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'sii_document_class_id'}"/>
</xpath>
```

The document_type model itself:

```
class sii_document_class(models.Model):
_name = 'sii.document_class'
_description = 'SII Document Class'

name = fields.Char(
    'Name', size=120)
doc_code_prefix = fields.Char(
    'Document Code Prefix', help="Prefix for Documents Codes on Invoices \
    and Account Moves. For eg. 'FAC' will build 'FAC 00001' Document Number")
code_template = fields.Char(
    'Code Template for Journal')
sii_code = fields.Integer(
    'SII Code', required=True)
document_letter_id = fields.Many2one(
    'sii.document_letter', 'Document Letter')
report_name = fields.Char(
    'Name on Reports',
    help='Name that will be printed in reports, for example "CREDIT NOTE"')
document_type = fields.Selection(
    [
        ('invoice', 'Invoices'),
        ('invoice_in', 'Purchase Invoices'),
        ('debit_note', 'Debit Notes'),
        ('credit_note', 'Credit Notes'),
        ('other_document', 'Other Documents')
    ],
    string='Document Type',
    help='It defines some behaviours on automatic journal selection and\
    in menus where it is shown.')
active = fields.Boolean(
    'Active', default=True)
dte = fields.Boolean(
    'DTE', required=True)
```

**SECOND EDIT**

This is the actual field in the form view which is giving me the error, everytime I click to select one document:

```
  <h6 style="color:red;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:900">
  <span t-field="o.journal_document_class_id.sii_document_class_id.name"/>
  </h6>
```

Comment: Can you post some code of this module? What purpose does this module have?

Comment: Hi @CZoellner I've edited my question with the codes, may You have a look?, Thank You very much

Comment: The purpose is to have a main menu, where you define a document, 4 or 5 fields, then with a Many2one, You call these definitions from an invoice, when I call it from the invoice then this happens...

Comment: I've edited my question again, with the actual field, but I think this error is somewhat related to this: https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/domain-filter-checking-for-product-in-many2many-list-in-sale-order-line-item-throws-javascript-error-no-conversion-for-undefined-on-empty-m2m-list-95445

Comment: I think when the field is empty or something not expected then it can't render it accordingly, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Is there a reason you're working with t-field (qweb)?

Comment: Should I change that? I think it is supposed to get odoo object properties, in this case 'o.journal_document_class_id.sii_document_class_id.name' I could be wrong tho

Comment: So you're not working on a printable report or something like that? How is your code loaded: qweb-xml or data-xml (\_\_openerp\_\_.py)?

Comment: Well no, this is just a Many2one I'm loading into this form, it should be data-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't use QWeb for normal view definitions (formular, tree, search, etc.).
2. You can't use dot-notation on normal view field definitions.

So first off create a related `Char` field on the model your view is for. Then just define a simple field in the view.

Example (close to your code above):

```py
class my_model(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'

    journal_document_class_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name="journal.document.class", string="Journal Doc Class")
    # related field
    sii_document_name = fields.Char(
        string="Sii Document Name",
        related="journal_document_class_id.sii_document_class_id.name")
```

```xml
<h6 style="color:red;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:900">
    <field name="sii_document_name"/>
</h6>
```

Comment: Hi @CZoellner, still the same error, I've changed everything as you told me :(, I don't know really

Comment: No, sorry, the error is gone, I've had to restart odoo server, but now there's another one, lol, anyways, thank You very much, gotta open another question for that if I can't find the solution :)